# Does anyone know why all of my elements are being rendered in a single column as if it were a <navbar>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]My component  is being rendered in a single column equal to the photo I attached, but it is wrong, it was to be a 5x4 array.

edi1: In an old version of the code I did not have this problem, however  I received some props, and since I have to constantly change the contents of the Component, I thought it was good to use state.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            {<RecipeItem list={this.state.searchString} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


File RecipeItem.js 
const RecipeList = ({ searchString }) => {
    return(
    <div>
        <img className="card-img-top img-fluid" src={searchString.thumbnail} alt={searchString.title} />
        <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{searchString.title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
                <strong>Ingredients: </strong>{searchString.ingredients}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

const RecipeItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-3 mt-4">
            <div className="card">
                {props.list && props.list.map((searchString, index) =>
                    <RecipeList searchString={searchString} key={index} />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what `<RecipeItem>` renders. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I updated with the code of RecipeItem.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying col-sm-3 before iterating on each element, you should apply the class on each iteration like this :

```
const RecipeItem = (props) => {
  return (
     props.list && props.list.map((searchString, index) =>
        <div className="card col-sm-3 mt-4">
          <RecipeList searchString={searchString} key={index} />
        </div>
      )
  )
}
```